# MVC4 append to existing class object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have ViewModel and I am doing

```
var model = from x in abc
            select new CompaniesVM { id = x.id ..etc}
```

then I want to execute another query and append the data to CompaniesVM instance. something like

```
var model2 = from f in def
            select new CompaniesVM {id = f.id ..etc}
```

then return the model to the view. I cannot use new keyword since It will create new instance object

I tried to create a new instance at the beginning of the call `var companyList = new CompaniesVM();` and then instead of `select new CompaniesVM` do `select companyList {companyList.id = x.id}` but it gives me a compilation error does not find the x.id

How do I fix it?

UPDATE

I need to execute the first condition then check if count()<5 then execute the second condition and append the result into one viewmodel. cannot be in a single call.

Comment: Your select queries returns collections of `CompaniesVM`. If you want to combine them, use `.concat` [How to: Concatenate Two Sequences (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386979(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: If you do not want to do a concat, why not create a view that is the union of the two tables and then you have just a single call to populate your model - no need to concat.

Comment: @StephenMuecke the viewmodel contains union of both tables. the first select gets records from one DB then I am checking if count()<5 execute the second statement and want to append to same object. Using .concat seems i have to put all in one query. How do I do separate queries and combine if neeed. thanks

Comment: Still not clear what you need. If `model.Count() < 5` (say it contains 3 items) you then execute the second query (which say returns 4 other items). Do you then want `model` to also include the results of `model2` (so that it now contains all 7 items)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thats correct it would contain 7 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the results of the second query to the first using `.concat`

```
var model = from x in abc select new CompaniesVM { id = x.id ..etc}
if (model.Count() < 5)
{
  model = model.ToList().concat(from f in def select new CompaniesVM {id = f.id ..etc})
}
```

Comment: after the concat I do model.ToList() and I get an exception: Unable to create a constant value of type 'ViewModels.CompaniesVM '. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context. What does it mean? Thanks.

Comment: I added `AsEnumerable()` to the first query and it worked. Do you know why I had to add it? what it does?

Comment: I was just about to correct my answer :) (you could have also used `.ToList()`). Its because `model` is in memory and you cannot join a set of data in the database with another set of data that is in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is create a view model which contains Union of both tables and get data in a single call.